# ASP updatepanels

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, jquery, updatepanel

I am implementing a shopping basket functionality(with common features) for a ASP.Net website and there are two buttons in each basket items(line items) which will increment/decrement the quantity and also a delete button. I need AJAX approach for my basket page. What is the best approach to accomplish my requirement? **Is it a good idea to use ASP update panels?** I am using a repeater to populate the basket. Any suggestions would be really appreciated..

**EDIT**
it seems people have found this question a bit senseless(sorry about that). I am using a user control for the basket that means that doesn't allow me to use Web Methods straight-away in the code-behind. I have voucher functionality + a post and package calculator in the same control, which needs to be updated based on user actions.

**Solution**
Initially got all this stuff to work as I expected by using asp AJAX updatepanels then realized it is **NOT** a good approach once I saw the response. The implemented a simple Web service to work with jQuery Ajax. I all fine now. happy days :)

Comment: Yes, it is a good idea if you want to use ASP.NET ajax anyway.

Comment: use Jquery ajax with httphandler. Call the handler on button (increment/decrement).

Answer (score 3):

Update panel will not be a good choice since you would have to put the whole repeater into the panel and it will be re-rendered by the JavaScript.

I would go with "Page-Methods". Add these methods to your code-behind:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void AddItem(int itemId)
{
    //code to increase quantity
}

[WebMethod]
public static void RemoveItem(int itemId)
{
    //code to decrease quantity
}
```

And then call these methods from JavaScript. A nice article about page methods can be found [here](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx)

Comment: The problem with this approach is it does,t work with User control (I should have mentioned it in the first place) finally I have decided to got for a web service instead. thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

well I am not sure about what you want to do, but if you need to make tow buttons to increase or decrease then you need to make some coding for this issue and after that you need to put it inside a update panel and you can add some animation to it using the UpdatePanelAnimationExtender to make it looks better.

that is it.

Comment: Actually I'm keeping basket details on the session. once you changed the quantity of a item, that should change the session values, page content (shipping cost, net value. etc...)